# Are jena queries lazy?

Tags: sparql, lazy-evaluation, jena

Currently I have the following code:

```
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
while(results.hasNext()){
            results.next();
            counter += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
```

Currently when I run this, each iteration of the loop can take from several seconds to a minute to execute. So my question is, are the results being processed in a lazy manner? and if so is there a way to make it find all results at once?

Thanks.

Comment: The performance of a SPARQL query depends on many things: the query itself, the kind of triple store you are querying against, what the data looks like, how much data there is, and what kind of environment - cpu, memory, etc - the program is running in. Since you've told us none of these things, it's basically not possible to answer the question as it is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (usually).  The work is done during calls to hasNext, depending on the query, the data and any inference set up.

See ResultSetFactory for operations to consume all the results at once.